# GooglecolabでCycleGANを実行したのに1エポックの実行時間が長すぎます

Tags: 機械学習, pytorch, google-colaboratory, gpu

以下のサイトに従ってGooglecolabでPytorchのCycleGANを実行したのですが1エポックに約30分も時間がかかってしまいます。このサイトでは1エポックに6分くらいかかると書いてありました。

[CycleGAN で画像変換する。](https://qiita.com/nomunomu/items/9de4aa447f502293a2f7)

ほかのサイトでも1エポックに6分当たりかかると書かれており私の実行時間よりとても短いです。なぜ私が実行すると30分もかかってしまうのかが分からず困っております。
GPUも設定しましたし、上のサイトに忠実に実行したはずなのに実行時間だけ大きく異なります。
実行したときのパラメータは以下の通りです。
[image: パラメータ1]
[image: パラメータ2]
バッチサイズは4にしてあり、バッチサイズを大きくしたら早くなるのではと思い32にしてみたのですが、バッチサイズを大きくするとRuntimeerror:cuda error:outofMemoryとなりエラーになってしまいます。
また、実行した出力画面は以下のとおりです。1エポックまで実行して中断しました。1エポックに1657秒かかってます。
[image: 実行した出力画面]

機械学習の知識があまりないので原因が全く分からないのですが、誰か分かる方がいましたら教えていただけますか。

Comment: qiitaの記事作成者の方からのコメント回答に「1エポック30分」との訂正？がありましたが、こちらで解決されたということで良いでしょうか？

Comment: 返信が遅くなってしまい申し訳ありません。無料のgooglecolabの方ではgpuにあたりとはずれがあり、外れのk80だと1エポックに30分かかると分かりました。以下の質問サイト様の方で解決致しました。https://teratail.com/questions/367471

Comment: マルチポスト先で解決されたとのこと、良かったです。こちらの質問もクローズ処理お願いいたします。

Comment: 承知しました。ありがとうございます。